# How to wait until a file is created in Rust?

Tags: file, rust

The file may or may not be created before my program starts, so I need to ensure that this file exists before proceeding. What is the most idiomatic way to do that?

Comment: Use [Path::exists](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.exists)?

Comment: It may be called continuously for a while. Is that optimal?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it uses `stat` on Unix like systems so it is as expensive as a system call.

Comment: Does that system call involves file system polling? I want to avoid that

Comment: Are you looking for a filesystem watcher like https://github.com/passcod/notify ?

Comment: Looks like it can't emit "created" event immediately when file already exists or something like that. So, first I must check if file exists using `Path::exists`, then I must register this watcher, and additionally I must handle case when file might be created between two previous operations (most likely using timeout and second check). I think that's not idiomatic way

Comment: @I60R: Can't you register the watcher prior to checking if the path exists, and cancel the watcher if it does exist?

Comment: Yes, that works for me

Answer (score 5):

Taking into account suggestions from comments I've written the following code:

```
fn wait_until_file_created(file_path: &PathBuf) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let mut watcher = notify::raw_watcher(tx)?;
    // Watcher can't be registered for file that don't exists.
    // I use its parent directory instead, because I'm sure that it always exists
    let file_dir = file_path.parent().unwrap();
    watcher.watch(&file_dir, RecursiveMode::NonRecursive)?;
    if !file_path.exists() {
        loop {
            match rx.recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(2))? {
                RawEvent { path: Some(p), op: Ok(op::CREATE), .. } => 
                    if p == file_path {
                        break
                    },
                _ => continue,
            }
        }
    }
    watcher.unwatch(file_dir)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This answer needs to be updated with which version of [notify](https://github.com/notify-rs/notify) was used. This does not compile with `v5.1`.